# App not loading images right???

Tags: android

I load the camera and take a picture, then set the picture taken into an imageview; however, the app always does the last image taken, not the current one.

So, if I open the app and take a picture, the image view is black. Close app, reopen and take another picture, the image view is now the first picture taken.

???

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg");
        System.out.println((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image.jpg"));
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

        setContentView(R.layout.image_process);
         bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image.jpg");
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're starting your *Picture Taking* activity with `startActivityForResult`, you need to move the code following `startActivityForResult(..` to the `onActivityResult` method:

```
/** Called when an activity called by using startActivityForResult finishes. */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Picture taken!");
  setContentView(R.layout.image_process);
  bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image.jpg");
  image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Worked. Answer Accepted!